# Microsoft azure site recovery

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am performing azure site recovery from vmware to azure through a site to site virtual private network. My on premise network bandwidth is 50mbps.

what will be the bandwidth in azure network?? is there any document or tool for this??

Comment: I think this depend on your location and local time (due to how many people are using the network). At my job I get about 1MB of download, and about 10MB for upload.

Comment: my location is south india. how can i check this?

Comment: There is no specific tool for this. I used Ubuntu's system monitor during the upload/download of a large file (10GB and 30GB) to Azure blob storage, and kept an eye on the Resources tab, which shows the current upload/download bandwidth being used.